# "Il était une fois" vs "Il y avait une fois" - what's the difference?

Tags: usage, locutions, synonymes

What's the difference between the "Il était une fois" and "Il y avait une fois"?

Answer (score 3):

Source : https://www.frenchclasses.com/audio/guinguette/voyages/1001cult/

- Les deux expressions sont-elles pour autant interchangeables?
- La réponse est non, en tout cas pas dans tous les cas.

> En principe "Il était une fois" est l’expression consacrée qui
>   commence une fable, un récit de fiction, un conte. Selon ce principe,
>   "il y avait une fois un prince charmant" est moins approprié que "il
>   était une fois un prince charmant".
>
> "Il était" (avec un ‘il’ impersonnel) est une vieille forme de "il y
>   avait" ou "c’était". De nombreuses chansons populaires commencent par
>   "il était", comme "Il était une bergère qui gardait ses moutons" ou
>   encore "Il était un petit navire", etc.

Voici un essai de rendre en anglais tout ça :

> In principle "il était une fois (i.e. once upon a time)" is the consecrated
>   expression that begins a fable, a narrative of fiction, a tale.
>   According to this principle, "il y avait une fois un prince charmant"
>   is less appropriate than "il était une fois un prince charmant".
>
> "Il était" (with an impersonal "il") (literary there was) is an old
>   form of "il y avait" or "c'était". Many popular songs begin with "Il
>   était", like "Il était une bergère qui gardait ses moutons (there was a
>   shepherdess who kept his sheep)" or "Il était un petit navire (there
>   was a little ship)", and so on.

Voir aussi les lemmes de wiktionnaire :

- [Il était une fois](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/il_%C3%A9tait_une_fois)
- [Il y avait une fois](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/il_y_avait_une_fois)