A translation of 'once upon a time'
Sometimes when reading, I find some books use ' il y avait une fois' meaning 'once upon a time', and others use  'il y etait une fois'. Which is correct?

Il était une fois plutôt que il y était une fois?

But the books are using 'y' as in  'there was', 'il y a' .

Hi @LynTagliaferri, could you provide more details and post passages from these books where you saw that? Il y etait une fois could simply be the canonical expression where y is added to refer to a place mentioned before. But it's not common.

If y is a typo (likely), duplicate of https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34018/il-%c3%a9tait-une-fois-vs-il-y-avait-une-fois-whats-the-difference

For example, you can see that all the titles of Sergio Leone's classic films were translated as 'Il était une fois'. Indeed, "Once Upon a Time in the West" became "Il était une fois dans l'Ouest", "Once upon a time...the Revolution ("Duck, You Sucker!") became "Il était une fois la révolution" and "Once Upon a Time in America" became "Il était une fois en Amérique". This translation creates a coherence and immediate recognition of these films while capturing the epic and narrative character suggested by the expression "Once Upon a Time".
Other examples of usage:
Il était une fois un roi et une reine qui vivaient dans un grand château. Once upon a time, there was a king and a queen who lived in a big castle.
Il était une fois un petit garçon qui aimait explorer la forêt.
Once upon a time, there was a little boy who loved to explore the forest.
Il était une fois une petite maison au bord de la mer où vivait une vieille dame. Once upon a time, there was a little house by the sea where an old lady lived.
See also
"Il était une fois" vs "Il y avait une fois" - what's the difference?
